# Usage of "(in)capable"

Tags: grammaticality, adjectives

I read the following question on meta: [Questions incapable of a simple answer](https://english.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/3102/questions-incapable-of-a-simple-answer)

Now I am confused: Is that a possible correct usage of "(in)capable"? Can a question be capable of an answer?

Wouldn't it have to be "incapable of being answered"? Or am I just confused by the possibly different usage of the German (my native language) "fähig"?

Comment: Rather than looking to validate the use of *incapable*, we should see if a better word exists.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The usage is acceptable, if I correctly understand the third sense of *incapable* in OED 1:

> “Of such a nature, or in such a condition, as not to allow or admit of; not admitting or susceptible of. ... Equivalent to ‘that cannot’ with an infinitive passive; e.g. *incapable of measurement*, or *incapable of being measured*”.

Comment: Thank you for the quick answer. With more research I should have been able to find something like this myself. +1 (for now)

Comment: @AlexanderKosubek "more research" goes ***before*** posting a question on ELU, or at least, before someone answers it! Good luck next time.

Comment: @kris I should have written "even more" research, as I did _some_ research before posting. And I know, mea culpa. I pledge to better myself!